# opencv_viz.lib cannot found in the opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, module

I am doing a project that can render 3d models. But after I downloaded the 3.4.6 version of OpenCV. The viz module is included in the source/modules file, but I don't have opencv_viz.lib in my opencv, so I can't import the library in the additional dependencies in the linker. How to solve this problem, this is my code below:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/viz.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include "stl_reader.h"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Start the timer
    auto start_time = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    // Load the STL file using the stl_reader library
    stl_reader::StlMesh<float, unsigned int> mesh("/Users/thore/Downloads/Wikipedia_puzzle_globe_3D_render.stl");

    // Create a vector to store the vertices of the mesh
    std::vector<cv::Vec3f> vertices;

    // Iterate through the triangles in the mesh and add their vertices to the vector
    for (size_t i = 0; i < mesh.num_tris(); i++) {
        const float* v1 = mesh.tri_corner_coords(i, 0);
        const float* v2 = mesh.tri_corner_coords(i, 1);
        const float* v3 = mesh.tri_corner_coords(i, 2);

        // Calculate the normal vector of the current triangle
        cv::Vec3f normal = cv::normalize(cv::Vec3f(
            (v2[1] - v1[1]) * (v3[2] - v1[2]) - (v2[2] - v1[2]) * (v3[1] - v1[1]),
            (v2[2] - v1[2]) * (v3[0] - v1[0]) - (v2[0] - v1[0]) * (v3[2] - v1[2]),
            (v2[0] - v1[0]) * (v3[1] - v1[1]) - (v2[1] - v1[1]) * (v3[0] - v1[0])
        ));

        // Calculate the dot product of the normal and the viewing direction
        float dot_product = cv::Vec3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f).dot(normal);

        // If the dot product is negative, the triangle is facing away from the viewer
        if (dot_product < 0.0f) {
            vertices.push_back(cv::Vec3f(v1[0], v1[1], v1[2]));
            vertices.push_back(cv::Vec3f(v2[0], v2[1], v2[2]));
            vertices.push_back(cv::Vec3f(v3[0], v3[1], v3[2]));
        }
    }
    // Create a window to display the 3D visualization
    viz::Viz3d window("3D Mesh Visualization");
    window.setBackgroundColor(cv::viz::Color::white());

    // Get the camera pose
    cv::Affine3f pose = window.getViewerPose();

    // Get the direction the camera is facing
    cv::Vec3f cam_dir = pose.rotation().inv() * cv::Vec3f(0, 0, 1);

    // Create a cloud object from the vertices
    viz::WCloud cloud(vertices);
    cloud.setRenderingProperty(cv::viz::POINT_SIZE, 2);
    cloud.setColor(cv::viz::Color::red());
    cloud.setRenderingProperty(cv::viz::REPRESENTATION, cv::viz::REPRESENTATION_SURFACE);
    cloud.setRenderingProperty(cv::viz::OPACITY, 0.5);

    // Add the cloud object to the window
    window.showWidget("3D Mesh", cloud);

    // End the timer
    auto end_time = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    // Calculate the duration of the execution in milliseconds
    auto duration_ms = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(end_time - start_time);

    // Print the duration of the execution
    cout << "Execution time: " << duration_ms.count() << " ms" << endl;

    // Start the 3D visualization
    while (!window.wasStopped())
    {
        window.spinOnce(1, true);
    }

    cv::moveWindow("Mesh Viewer", 0, 0);


    return 0;
}
```

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl cv::viz::Widget::~Widget(void)" (??1Widget@viz@cv@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: __cdecl cv::viz::Widget3D::~Widget3D(void)" (??1Widget3D@viz@cv@@QEAA@XZ)   DSPC    C:\Users\thore\Desktop\DSPC\DSPC\Source.obj 1

Comment: I'd guess that your download simply wasn't configured to build that module, you might need to compile from source or find another source of binaries